# How can I add an option to pay with cryptocurrency in an android app using Java?

Tags: wallets, java, android

For my college assignment I have been tasked with creating an app that among other things allows a user to pay for services using an ICO Token (ERC20 contract), How do I go about doing this? The wallet that I will be using will be MetaMask and the token is currently deployed to the Kovan testnet. Any help would be greatly appreciated as Google is comming up empty on this one.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What do you mean by "option to pay"? A UI button? A smart contract that handles a treasury?

Comment: Once a user clicks the button saying pay, which is next to the service they want, maybe a page would open that allows the user to send ICO tokens to an address which represents the business, or if that doesn't make sense maybe open metamask wallet and send the token from there, do you think this can be done?